# What is the max level in Alto’s Adventure?

Tags: altos-adventure

What is the maximum possible level in Alto’s Adventure?

The character select screen indicates that the last character is unlocked at level 51, but can you keep leveling up beyond that?

Comment: My girlfriend is about to beat the last level (they ask for an insane score). Stay tuned!

Comment: I didn't read the "51" in your message. She's at level 60 already! Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just finished level 60, and it says, "Congratulations! You have completed all the goals!" The last goal took us a long time.

Here's a screenshot of the pause screen when starting a new game.

[image: Pause screen with completed goals message]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the completed goals screen?

Comment: Added, @StevenVascellaro.

Answer (score 0):

My girlfriend is at level 60, so there are more levels after level 51. After unlocking the last character in level 51, the message that told how many levels were left for unlocking a new character simply starts saying that there are X levels left. With that in mind, the last level seems to be level 60.