# What is the max level in Alto’s Odyssey?

Tags: altos-odyssey

What is the maximum possible level in Alto’s Odyssey?

The previous game (Alto’s Adventure) [capped at level 60](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321956/181240), so I’m curious what the max level is in the sequel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has the same level 60 cap. You can find the list of goals for each level on the below link:

https://appunwrapper.com/2018/02/21/altos-odyssey-list-of-goals-for-all-levels/